# How to handle polymorphism with vectors of a class the right way in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, vector, polymorphism

I'm currently implementing an entity component system and working on a way to store vectors of components, each vector of one component type should be contiguous, this is why I'm using `vector<Component>*` and not `vector<Component*>`. I'm new to C++ and coming from Java, so I'm still struggling with some concepts regarding memory layout and polymorphism.

I've fully implemented a (seemingly) working version of this. I have a vector for each type of component there is (e.g. PositionComponent, GravityComponent, etc.), because components differ in size. But because the amount of types isn't known in compile time, I need a vector of pointers to point to these ComponentLists of different types. I'm using reinterpret_casts with a map which keeps track of the component types to accomplish this, but there has to be a less undefined way of doing this. (Hopefully!)

Here is a picture of what I want to achieve:
[Component List Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aybMK.png)

**Edit: I just notices that my program crashes with a segmentation fault after the `return 0` in the main function. The call stack seems to be corrupted, as it jumps to some random address instead of actually returning. So my system is definately flawed.**

Main function:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    EntityComponentSystem ecs;

    // Fill with some components
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        ecs.addComponent(AComponent());
        ecs.addComponent(BComponent());
        ecs.addComponent(CComponent());
    }

    // Print all components
    std::cout << "Components: " << std::endl;

    // Print AComponents
    std::cout << "A Components: " << std::endl;
    ComponentList<AComponent>* aComps = ecs.getComponentList<AComponent>();
    aComps->print();

    // Print BComponents
    std::cout << std::endl << "B Components: " << std::endl;
    ComponentList<BComponent>* bComps = ecs.getComponentList<BComponent>();
    bComps->print();

    // Print CComponents
    std::cout << std::endl << "C Components: " << std::endl;
    ComponentList<CComponent>* cComps = ecs.getComponentList<CComponent>();
    cComps->print();

    return 0;
}
```

EntityComponentSystem class:

```cpp
class EntityComponentSystem
{
    private:
        // To shorten some things up
        typedef std::vector<ComponentList<Component>*>::iterator                    ComponentListIterator;
        typedef std::unordered_map<std::type_index, Component::TypeID>::iterator    MapIterator;

        std::vector<ComponentList<Component>*>                  comps;          // Indexed by TypeID
        std::unordered_map<std::type_index, Component::TypeID>  componentMap;   // Maps typeid(Component) to TypeID

    public:
        EntityComponentSystem() : comps(), componentMap() {}
        ~EntityComponentSystem()
        {
            for(ComponentListIterator it = comps.begin(); it < comps.end(); ++it)
            {
                delete (*it);
            }
        }

        template<typename T>
        void addComponent(const T& component)
        {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be of type Component!");

            MapIterator found = componentMap.find(typeid(T));
            ComponentList<T>* componentList = nullptr;

            if(found == componentMap.end()) // This component derivative hasn't been added yet, so add it
            {
                componentList = new ComponentList<T>();
                int componentId = comps.size();
                this->comps.push_back(reinterpret_cast<ComponentList<Component>*>(componentList));
                this->componentMap[typeid(T)] = componentId;
            }
            else
            {
                componentList = reinterpret_cast<ComponentList<T>*>(comps[found->second]);
            }

            componentList->push(component);
        }

        template<typename T>
        ComponentList<T>* getComponentList()
        {
            Component::TypeID id = getComponentTypeId<T>();
            if(id == Component::TYPE_ID_UNKNOWN) return nullptr;
            return reinterpret_cast<ComponentList<T>*>(comps[id]);
        }

        template<typename T>
        Component::TypeID getComponentTypeId()
        {
            static_assert(std::is_base_of<Component, T>::value, "T must be of type Component!");

            MapIterator found = componentMap.find(typeid(T));

            if(found == componentMap.end())
            {
                return Component::TYPE_ID_UNKNOWN;
            }

            return found->second;
        }
};
```

ComponentList class:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class ComponentList
{
    private:
        std::vector<T>      components;

    public:
        void push(const T& t)
        {
            this->components.push_back(t);
        }

        void print()
        {
            for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = components.begin(); it != components.end(); ++it)
            {
                it->test();
            }
        }
};
```

Base Component class and its derivatives:

```cpp
class Component
{
    public:
        typedef uint16_t    TypeID;
        static const TypeID TYPE_ID_UNKNOWN = -1;

        virtual ~Component() = default;

        virtual void test()
        {
            std::cout << "I'm the base!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class AComponent : public Component
{
    private:
        static int  nextValue;
        int     someValue;      // To test if different sizes of Component derivatives cause any problems!

    public:
        AComponent()
        {
            this->someValue = nextValue++;
        }

        void test()
        {
            std::cout << "I'm AComponent! Value: " << someValue << std::endl;
        }
};

int AComponent::nextValue = 0;

class BComponent : public Component
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            std::cout << "I'm BComponent!" << std::endl;
        }
};

class CComponent : public Component
{
    public:
        void test()
        {
            std::cout << "I'm CComponent!" << std::endl;
        }
};
```

Comment: Use [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to be kept in the container class instance.

Comment: Agreed, make sure to compile with `-std=c++11` (or 14, or 17) to have them available.

Comment: I don't see your question, however, I do see that you don't initialize all of your variables. So you must be seeing unexpected effects.

Comment: There’s [a library](https://github.com/skypjack/entt) that does this really well. So well in fact that it is used in Minecraft Bedrock Edition. It doesn’t use `reinterpret_cast`, it doesn’t use `std::unordered_map` or `std::type_index`. It doesn’t require components inherit from a common base (that’s a very Java thing to do). Components should just be POD structs (not classes with behaviour). An entity is just an integer (where are your entities?). I think you could gain a lot by looking at how to do this properly.

Comment: That library has a [gitter channel](https://gitter.im/skypjack/entt) where you can ask questions about the library or ask the author about implementation details.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I agree on using smart pointers for less error proneness, but I don't see how they help me here.

Comment: @Kerndog73 Thanks, I'll look into the library. And you're right, the inheritance from a common base really is redundant (and java-ish), but it's helpful in this little test (common "test" functions) and I'm too used to it, I guess.

Comment: @JVApen Well, I haven't encountered errors yet, but I'm just not sure if I'm missing some potential bug here. Also, which variables are uninitialized? I don't find any.

Comment: @Kerndog73 And regarding entities: I haven't implemented them yet because my main problem is the storage of components. But they're easily implemented, there just needs to be a mapping from the entity IDs to the component index for each ComponentList.

Comment: @DanksaGrabowski This mapping from entity IDs to component indicies is done with a sparse set rather than an unordered_map in the library I linked. It can be easily implemented if you don’t care about performance. ;-)

Comment: @DanksaGrabowski If you just used a map then you wouldn’t be able to sort components efficiently and perfect SoA iteration wouldn’t be possible so the naive approach is much worse than you might think.

Comment: @danksa I must have been confused as I meant someValue, though looking at this again it is correct. Just an unfamiliar way of initializing